# rebuilding specific indexes in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Working on rebuilding specific indexes online from a database with over 5000 tables.
I collected the tables by following sql

```
select tables
from information_schema.tables
where table_name like '%2016%' or table_name like '%2017%';
```

Help requested for rebuilding all the tables from this result of tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Olla's script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) to do any kind of index maintenance on SQL Server. It's well documented and very well written code.